# Criar tipo utilizando classe de uma estrutura, e usar o mesmo tipo dentro da classe

Tags: c++

Atualmente preciso criar uma coleção de classes que representam nodes (fragmentos) da AST (árvore síntatica abstrata) de um interpretador. Agora, por exemplo, dêei uma visão geral nos templates do C++ e tentei declarar dois membros (`left` e `right`) para uma classe `ASSIGNOP`, que seriam ambos nodes.

```
#ifndef AST_H
#define AST_H

struct ast
{
    template<typename T>
    class ASSIGNOP
    {
    public:
        T *left;
        T *right;
    }
} Ast;

#endif
```

Não testei esse código porque tenho que aprender à usar o make ainda...

Então, o problema é que os membros de `ASSIGNOP` não são considerados nodes (ainda não sei muito sobre templates). Preciso fazer com que sejam forçados para ser uma das classes dentro de `Ast`. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
struct ast
{
    class VARIABLE
    {
    public:
        double value;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class ASSIGNOP
    {
    public:
        T *left;
        T *right;
    };

    ASSIGNOP<VARIABLE> AssignOp;
} Ast;

int main()
{
    Ast.AssignOp.left = new ast::VARIABLE{ 1.23 };
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Embora eu ache que esse código precise de várias melhorias tanto em termo de nomenclatura das classes/variáveis como em termos de organização e manutenção do código (`left`/`right` sendo membros públicos de `ASSIGNOP`, `Ast` sendo uma variável global etc.).